# how to use the "or" in the negative form?

Tags: grammar

when I say "he does something that is not good or serious"  what do I mean by that

- He does something that is not good and is not serious
- He does something that is not good and is serious

the adjective after or is it also negative ?

Comment: You haven't used 'or' in your examples! The negative of 'or' is 'nor'.

Comment: I think you want to say "He does something that is neither good nor serious."

Answer (score 1):

*Not A or B* generally means neither *A* nor *B*. Consider

> In many states in the US, voters who are **not registered Democrats or [registered] Republicans** cannot vote in primary elections.

But it’s not as unambiguous as the *neither*-*nor* version. It’s possible for the *not* to bind only to the *A* rather than to the entire disjunction. Here’s an example:

> I wonder why the baby isn’t interested in her bottle. I guess she’s either **not hungry or sleepy**.

But note that in that example, the *either* is nearly mandatory. Without the *either*, the phrase strongly invites interpretation as a *neither*-*nor*. And then the [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) kicks in and flags that interpretation as odd and thus unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

The negative of "or" is "nor".

So your sentence is

- "He does something that is neither good nor serious"

Comment: I’m a student and this is a question in my book . Is the sentence grammatically wrong ?

Comment: Then, repeat the question of your book **literally**.

Comment: if a person does the something that is not good or serious ,that means they are < naughty _ cruel > I can’t answer because I don’t understand the correct translation

Comment: @smile there is no word for or in  your language?? that is not good, that is not serious.

Answer (score 0):

He does something that is not good **or** is not serious.

**It's one or the other**. He does something that is not good.
He does something that is not serious.

He eats hamburgers **or** hotdogs at picnics. Not both.

You can translate the word or into your language and it will yield the same thing.